# Asp.net performance issue when storing sessions in Redis

Tags: asp.net, session, redis, session-state, stackexchange.redis

In converting from storing sessions in SQL to instead storing sessions in Redis, we are seeing a major performance issue. I hope you are able to give us some hints on what could cause this.

The technical setup:

- An asp.net website compiled in .net framework 4.72.
- An old Redis version 3.2 (Microsoft compiled version for Windows) running on same server.
- Nuget: [ASP.NET Session State Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider)
- Nuget: Stackexchange.Redis

When running a performance load testing, with increasing number of virtual users (VUs), the server at about 400-500 virtual users hits some kind of wall, only processing a low number of requests as seen in this diagram:

[image: performance issue diagram]

The performance testing is made by k6.io from a remote server.

Another tests shows that when overloaded, the server for 1-2 seconds stops processing and then processes a lot in less than 1 seconds, and then stops again and so on. So it experiences some kind of congestions, maybe a full queue or lock of some kind.

Looking into the server CPU usage, it just drops significantly when the issues arises.

I can only reproduce it on our server, not my local machine, even though I have tried replicating the same setup.

Same issue whether serializing data to Redis using Binary og JSON serializer.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but I have a question for you: what factors have moved you to abandon Redis to store sessions? You probably won't have perf issues using Redis.

Comment: There really isn't much to go on here. It sounds like something is blocking your app from talking to redis. Most likely a blocked thread or something in IIS that's stopping your app from doing what it needs to. Are you seeing any kind of errors popping out from the StackExchange library (e.g. timeouts - could try setting more aggressive timeotus in the config to force the issue)? if so can you add those. Is there anything blocked in your application?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It appeared that Stackexchange.Redis was not updated to latest version. Updating it to latest version resolved my issue